# How to work with subselects in combination with PreparedStatements?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

For example I have the following SQL Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer c 
WHERE 2 = (SELECT count(*)
           FROM account a
           WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id);
```

How can I transform that SQL statement to a prepared statement command?

Comment: replace the constants with placeholders and then prepare them

Answer (score 1):

```
String queryString = " SELECT * FROM customer c";
queryString += " WHERE ? = (SELECT count(*) FROM account a WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id)";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
stmt.setInt(1, theCountYouLookFor) // theCountYouLookFor would be 2 in your example
```